# Why is "the temporary is part of an expression at the end of a block" an error?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, temporary

This is likely a textbook case of me not understanding some of the technicalities of the borrow checker, but it would be nice if someone could clear this up for me.

I have this (incredibly simplified) chunk of code, which compiles perfectly fine.

```
pub struct Example(pub Vec<String>);

impl Example {
  pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&String> {
    self.0.iter()
  }
}

pub fn some_condition(_: &str) -> bool {
  // This is not important.
  return false;
}

pub fn foo() -> bool {
  let example = Example(vec!("foo".to_owned(), "bar".to_owned()));
  let mut tmp = example.iter();
  tmp.all(|x| some_condition(x))
}

pub fn main() {
  println!("{}", foo());
}
```

However, the first thing that I tried (which, in my mind, should be equivalent to the above), was eliding the temporary variable `tmp` altogether, as follows

```
pub fn foo() -> bool {
  let example = Example(vec!("foo".to_owned(), "bar".to_owned()));
  example.iter().all(|x| some_condition(x))
}
```

But this version produces the following error.

```
error[E0597]: `example` does not live long enough
  --> so_temporary.rs:23:3
   |
23 |   example.iter().all(|x| some_condition(x))
   |   ^^^^^^^-------
   |   |
   |   borrowed value does not live long enough
   |   a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
24 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `example` dropped here while still borrowed
   | ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl std::iter::Iterator`
   |
   = note: The temporary is part of an expression at the end of a block. Consider forcing this temporary to be dropped sooner, before the block's local variables are dropped. For example, you could save the expression's value in a new local variable `x` and then make `x` be the expression at the end of the block.
```

Now, obviously, the note at the end of the error is an excellent suggestion, and it's why I introduced the temporary to fix the problem. But I don't understand *why* that fixes the problem. What's different about the lifetimes of my `tmp` variable versus `example.iter()` embedded into the expression directly, that makes one work and one fail?

Comment: [I further simplified and debugged your example here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=918aa40826b8ded7350ba1ee09e5231f). It's really bizarre, I think this might qualify as a compiler bug.

Comment: @pretzelhammer And it can be easily fixed in `std` without touching the compiler. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=99ccd7f25a03283497a7c75e17e0a10e

Comment: Although it's funny that this works without needing the extra binding at all.

Comment: @PeterHall Now I'm just doubly confused. Why does *that* fix it? o.O

Comment: @PeterHall the compiler bug, in my opinion, is that I would expect both `impl Iterator + '_` and `impl Iterator<Item = &i32>` used in the return position of the function to be resolved to the concrete type `std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>` and behave identically to the concrete type in all scenarios, without any additional hacks or workarounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has essentially the same answer as [Why do I get "does not live long enough" in a return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53586321) and its somewhat explained in the error itself, but I'll elaborate. This behavior is the same with a normal block expression:

```
pub struct Example(pub Vec<String>);

impl Example {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&String> {
        self.0.iter()
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let foo = {
        let example = Example(vec!("foo".to_owned(), "".to_owned()));
        example.iter().all(String::is_empty)
    };
    println!("{}", foo);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `example` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         example.iter().all(String::is_empty)
   |         ^^^^^^^-------
   |         |
   |         borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
13 |     };
   |     -- ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the destructor for type `impl Iterator`
   |     |
   |     `example` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: the temporary is part of an expression at the end of a block;
           consider forcing this temporary to be dropped sooner, before the block's local variables are dropped
help: for example, you could save the expression's value in a new local variable `x` and then make `x` be the expression at the end of the block
   |
12 |         let x = example.iter().all(String::is_empty); x
   |         ^^^^^^^                                     ^^^
```

The [scope of temporary values](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes) is often the *statement* in which they were created. In the code above `example` is a variable and it is destroyed at the end of the block. However, `example.iter()` creates a temporary `impl Iterator` and its temporary scope is the full `let foo = ...` statement. So the steps when evaluating this are:

- evaluate the result of `example.iter().all(...)`
- drop `example`
- assign result to `foo`
- drop `impl Iterator`

You can probably see where this can go wrong. The reason introducing a variable works is because it forces any temporaries to be dropped sooner. The case is slightly different when talking about functions, but the effect is the same:

> Temporaries that are created in the final expression of a function body are dropped *after* any named variables bound in the function body, as there is no smaller enclosing temporary scope.

Regarding the comments:

- The reason it works when `impl Iterator` is replaced with `std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>` (in pretzelhammer's example) is because the drop checker *knows* that `slice::Iter` doesn't access `example` on drop whereas it has to assume that `impl Iterator` does.
- The reason it works with `fn my_all(mut self, ...)` (in Peter Hall's example) is because `all` takes the iterator by reference but `my_all` takes it by value. The temporary `impl Iterator` is consumed and destroyed before the end of the expression.

From looking at various Rust issues relating to this, its clear that some would consider this a bug. Its definitely not obvious that `{ ...; EXPR }` and `{ ...; let x = EXPR; x }` could be different. However, since diagnostics and documentation have been added to reinforce and explain this behavior, I have to assume these temporary scoping rules allow for more reasonable code than not.

Comment: Way late to the game here, but the other problem is that in the `{ ...; let x = EXPR; x }` causes clippy to complain since logically this shouldn't be necessary.