# Turning a RefMut into a &mut

Tags: rust

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Weak;

struct Elem {
    attached_elem: Weak<RefCell<Elem>>,
    value: i32,
}

impl Elem {
    fn borrow_mut_attached_elem(&self) -> &mut Elem {
        //what should this line be?
        self.attached_elem.upgrade().unwrap().borrow_mut()
    }
}

fn main(){}
```

I have tried some similar other lines but nothing has worked so far, even the experimental cell_leak feature for RefMut.

I don't mind changing the signature of the function I just want to reduce the overhead of getting a mutable reference to the attached_elem from an Elem.

Comment: why do you have a `RefCell` if you want to return a plain `&mut` ?

Comment: @Netwave because `Rc`/`Weak` don't provide mutable access to their interior

Comment: @kmdreko, yes I understand that. But then returning a `&mut` may not be the correct approach. I wanted to know if `Weak<RefCell>` was a clear constrain or it comes deviated from other problem.

Comment: use nightly api https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefMut.html#method.leak

Comment: @Netwave I'm using Weak<RefCell> due to needing possibly circular references (Weak) and needing to be able mutate what those references refer to (RefCell)

Comment: @Stargateur `RefMut::leak()` will leave the attached element permanently borrowed. It's hard to be 100% certain, but it's probably not desired here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> what should this line be?

There is nothing you can put in that line to (safely) satisfy the function signature - and that's for good reason. While `RefCell` does allow obtaining `&mut T` from a `RefCell<T>` (that's why it exists), it must guarantee that only one mutable reference exist at a time. It does so by only providing a temporary reference whose lifetime is tied to the `RefMut<T>` wrapper. Once the wrapper is dropped, the value is marked as no longer borrowed, so the reference must not outlive it.

If Rust were to allow you to return a naked `&mut Elem`, you'd be able to use the reference after the `RefCell` has ceased being marked as borrowed. In that case, what's to stop you from calling `borrow_mut_attached_elem()` again, and obtain a second mutable reference to the same `Elem`?

So you'll definitely need to change the signature. If you just need to give outside code temporary access to `&mut Elem`, the easiest way is to accept a closure that will receive it. For example:

```
fn with_attached_elem<R>(&self, f: impl FnOnce(&mut Elem) -> R) -> R {
    let rc = self.attached_elem.upgrade().unwrap();
    let retval = f(&mut *rc.borrow_mut());
    retval
}
```

You'd call it to do something with the element, e.g.:

```
elem.with_attached_elem(|e| e.value += 1);
```

`with_attached_elem` takes care to return the value returned by the closure, allowing you to collect data from `&mut Elem` and propagate it to the caller. For example, to pick up the value of the attached element you could use:

```
let value = elem.with_attached_elem(|e| e.value);
```

Comment: This uses some mythical looking language features that I now have motivation to go and learn, thank you rusty sensei.

Comment: @Ripytide You're welcome. :) If you're curious about `impl FnOnce()`, it's just a shorter way to write a generic. The cryptic `&mut *foo` is the same as `foo.deref_mut()`, but doesn't require `use std::ops::DerefMut`. (Normally you don't have to do either because `foo.some_method()` uses consults `DerefMut` automatically if `some_method()` doesn't exist on the type of `foo` itself - but here we actually need `&mut Elem`.) As for why an explicit `retval` is necessary, I was surprised myself on that oddity, but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53586321/1600898) if you're curious.

Comment: @Ripytide Also, if you don't need the return value of the closure (if it's called for side effect, like in my example, rather than to extract data), then you can omit the `R` and simplify the signature to the more tame `with_attached_elem(&self, f: impl FnOnce(&mut Elem))`.